# What is before and after keydown in Textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I do not want to allow to press the function key like (F1,F2..etc),tabular key and also do not add any characters too.

for that one below code which is not working from my site.

```js
document.getElementById("code").addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    var oldOne = this.value;
 var newOne = (this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)).toLowerCase();
    if(oldOne==newOne){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
 document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Is it the same: "+(oldOne==newOne)+", Before: "+oldOne+", After: "+newOne;
})
```

```html
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: What is not working and what's your desired result?

Comment: It says that it is not the same, when it is. For example type apple, then press ctrl. It would say "false" when it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because convert charcode that is out of available char range `[32, 126]` would produce a `""`, while it seems like a empty string, it accounts to length, and can't be trim like a space, so `"apple" + "ctrl"`' s length is `6` while it displays as `"apple"`, you should better use

```
if (e.keyCode < 32 || e.keyCode > 126) {
  // This is not a valid char, do something to ignore
}
```

to ignore those special chars, rather than convert it to string, append to current value then compare with oldValue.

Comment: Np, I console logged your snippet then find out this thing. I also learned.

Answer (score 1):

When you're writing

```
String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
```

Then you're always getting a string even if you press though you're not seeing any change in the value, the String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) is getting something, the string format of the key, it's not a blank string so you're always getting false in the if.

Either you can check in the keycode or you can check after keyup.

Answer (score 0):

`keydown` event give you the state of object before your character is written.
`keyup events give you the state of object after it's written.

You may want to do something like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ncgvvby/)):

```
document.getElementById("ta").addEventListener("keydown", function () {
    this.oldValue = this.value;
});
document.getElementById("ta").addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    var oldOne = this.oldValue;
    var newOne = this.value;
    if(oldOne == newOne){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Is it the same: "+(oldOne==newOne)+", Before: "+oldOne+", After: "+newOne;
})
```

Comment: this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)).toLowerCase() also gives what we typed, then why is it not working?